# Overlay line on scatter plot

Tags: stata

In `Stata`, is there a way to overlay a line when the slope and `y`-intercept are known, onto a `twoway scatter Y X`?

For example, if the slope were `slope` and the y-intercept were `yint`, and the Y values were in an array called `Y` and the X values were in an array called `X` what would the syntax be?

Lets say we want to overlay `y=2x+1`, where `x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]` and `y = [3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PearlySpencer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `twoway function`:

```
twoway function y=2*x+1, range(0 5)
```

And as with any `twoway` graph, you can combine it with `scatter`:

```
twoway scatter var1 var2 || function y=2*x+1, range(0 5)
```

Here's a toy example:

```
clear
set obs 20

generate x = rnormal(3, 2)
generate y = rnormal(5, 2)

twoway scatter y x  || function y=2*x+1, range(0 5)
```

[image]